# Creating DbCommand does get timeout assigned from DBContext

Tags: ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I have ASP.NET Core 2.2 application using EF Core. In startup.cs i am setting `CommandTimeout` to 60 seconds

```
services.AddDbContext<CrowdReason.WMP.Data.Entities.WMPContext>(options => 
   options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                  sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60)));
```

Then i am executing the stored proc using the following code. Please note the values of `t1`, `t2` and `t3` in comments

```
    public static async Task<int?> prcDoWork(this WMPContext dbContext, int id, int userID)
    {
        var t1 = dbContext.Database.GetCommandTimeout();            
        // t1 is 60. Same as what i set in startup.cs

        using (var connection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection())
        {
            var t2 = connection.ConnectionTimeout;                                
            //t2 is 15

            using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {                    
                var p1 = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
                {
                    Value = id
                };
                var p2 = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int)
                {
                    Value = userID
                };
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.prcDoWork";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

                var t3 = cmd.CommandTimeout;
                //t3 is 30

                await dbContext.Database.OpenConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var result = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(result);
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand that `ConnectionTimeout` is different from `CommandTimeout`.
However issue is when i create command using `connection.CreateCommand()` its not automatically getting the timeout from DBContext

Answer (score 0):

EF Core works on top of the underlying System.Data implementation (in your case System.Data.SqlClient) and uses it to perform its DB operations. All settings you make will only reflect the way EF uses this underlying implementation.

When you use the `GetDbConnection` method you get a reference to an `SqlConnection` class from the `System.Data.SqlClient` assembly that knows nothing about EF and its settings and cannot be expected to honor the `RelationalOptionsExtension.CommandTimeout` from the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly.

To have EF settings respected you should use the `RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` method.